# Saw hundreds of warning on Latest Chrome F12 device mode when scrolling jtsage-TimeFlipBox?

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

The specific warning message is:

***Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.***

This issue can also be reproduced easily in the demo site by JTSage if you use chrome F12 "Device" mode -- many warning in F12 console.

http://dev.jtsage.com/DateBox/jqm/timeflipbox/

http://dev.jtsage.com/DateBox/

Is it something to be concerned about? Occasionally my Chrome simulator would freeze. But I do not know for sure if this is related to those warnings.

I have also googled a bit to find below link, but I do not know enough on how to apply their suggestions on jtsage timeflipbox yet:

https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula/issues/468

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
.ui-datebox-container {
  touch-action: none;
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks for the css, and thanks for the reference!!!

Comment: This will be added to the main css for the project shortly. https://github.com/jtsage/jtsage-datebox/issues/428