# How to display text values with jQuery slider?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

My goal is to have a slider where sliding will change an  info text.

The jQuery mobile docs show unfortunatelly only numeric values: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/slider/

At the moment I am using a select field:

```
<select name="condition" id="filter_condition"> 
    <option value="18">Average</option> 
    <option value="13">Good</option>
    <option value="277">Bad</option>
</select>
```

As in this example the values are not 1-3 and not in order.

Instead of showing the select field, I would like to show a slider, where bad is on the left and good on the right.

Is this possible with jQuery mobile? I found only examples with numeric values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't fully understand why Your values shall be not ordered, but anyway, here is my proposal.

If this is not exactly what You expect, fell free to update Your question with more details.

In Your example, You just only need to create the three slider sectors corresponding with Your options and, obviously, the relationship with these. Use `cases[val].value` to filter out what You need. The `input.change` event is Your friend here.

```js
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page-one", function() {
  var cases = [{value:277, label:"bad"},{value:18, label:"average"},{value:13, label:"good"}];
  $(".full-width-slider input").on("change", function() {
    var val = ($(this).val()/100)|0;
    $(".full-width-slider h3").text(cases[val].label);
  });
});
```

```css
/* Hide the number input */
.full-width-slider input {
  display: none !important;
}
.full-width-slider .ui-slider-track {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.full-width-slider h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="page-one" data-role="page">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div class="full-width-slider">
        <h3 class="ui-bar ui-bar-a ui-corner-all">bad</h3>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="299" value="0" autocomplete="off" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is another example about the `slider` events: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44519349/4845566

Comment: Thank you, Looks great. I am trying to implement but the values do not change and I get this error on moving the slider: "[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive."

Comment: The error keeps showing up, but the values change now. Somehow also I am not able to add more values: value:7, label:"Very Good"},{value:1, label:"Unused"}. Still only 3 changes.

Comment: OK, got it :-) Thank you. The error about the intervention must be something else within my code.

Comment: @merlin The error You mentioned is well-known, apply `touch-action: none;` to the container. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50594338/4845566

Comment: Great! Thank you, your help was very usefull.